# Emission material reflecting other emissions

Tags: texturing

I have been working on creating a material to simulate LEDs and have produced this:

[image]

Although I am happy overall with the result I have not been able to resolve the issue of the yellow reflections on the other LEDs, this is the node tree I have been using:

[image]

The material is uniform except for the change in emission colour, I therefore have two questions:

1. Is there a way in which to remove the coloured reflection and still retain the exact effect created?
2. Why is it that only the yellow light is reflected and the yellow LED does not behave this way, I have checked multiple times that the node tree settings are exactly the same.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you use an Anisotropic node in your material? That is what's causing reflections

Comment: It produces an effect that is desirable for my purposes, however, why is it that only yellow reflections behave that way?

Comment: I don't see any anisotropy effect on the spheres. All reflections must be visible it just so happens that from this angle yellow ones stand out more.

Comment: Upon further investigation i found that the same behavior does indeed happens with all the colours, so from this am I to understand the answer to question 1 is a no?

Comment: Why do you want to remove this, as the reflection (if not its hard edges) is realistic for gloss LEDs, e.g. the green reflected in the red here https://i1.adis.ws/s/maplin/CJ64U_set/Components/Electronics+Components/LEDs+%26+Displays/Individual+LEDs/3mm+Red+LED.jpg?locale=en-GB,en-

Comment: I am now leaving it in as it has been minimised with the methods in others' answers, but the reason I wanted to remove it was because the yellow was very noticeable in a zoomed out render and looked quite unappealing.

Comment: Just for a final note I decided to replicate real LEDs with the emission strength (increasing green strength, heavily decreasing yellow strength and partially decreasing red strength), this made a much more realistic scene and the light behavior seemed to work much better many thanks to everyone for their help on this :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the effect is more noticeable with the yellow is due to how the colors are made up of components of Red, Green, Blue in conjunction with the high strength of the emission. The Red is pure red, the Green is pure green, while the Yellow is a mix of red and green. Since your emission is high (10) the rendered pixels in the camera will be truncated to an upper limit of 1.0. So for the Red LED the pixels will be around RGB values of (10,0,0), the Yellow (10,10,0) and the Green (0,10,0) and these are truncated to become Red (1,0,0), Yellow (1,1,0), Green (0,1,0). Adding in the reflection from the Yellow LED on the Red LED (assuming, say, 10% reflection) you'll get (11,1, 0) which will become (1,1,0) (yellow). The Red reflecting on the Yellow will be (11, 10,0) which will become (1,1,0). The Yellow reflecting on the Green will become (1,11,0) which will become (1,1,0) when values above 1.0 are clipped. ie, so Red + Yellow reflection becomes yellow, Yellow + Red reflection becomes yellow, Yellow + Green reflection becomes yellow - so it appears that there is no reflection of the Red and Green LEDs as they are 'lost' in the saturated yellow emission.

That's essentially what I believe is happening here. I don't think I've explained that too well - hope it makes sense.

I *think* this would actually be similar to how this would behave in the real world - although less pronounced since the human eye has a wide band sensitivity to light rather than the strict narrow banding in Blender's RGB model.

Answer (score 1):

Yellow reflecting in outer colors because yellow is Green + Red in RGB color model. So yellow has match more color information then red or green. This effect uses in anaglyph glasses.

If you want to set different color in reflections, try to use light path node. This setup change color in reflections, so yellow color will be invisible, in outer reflections:

[image]

Outer way is use the  anaglyph glasses principle. If you set color of reflecting as blue, yellow will not reflect, becouse where is no red or green in blue:

[image]

Comment: I found that with these methods the effect was dulled but still noticeable, even when combining the methods.

Comment: @NickBosse maybe, you have not fully pure colors

Comment: I did it again and found that the second method removes the yellow reflection but then all reflections are replaced with the blue, did you manage to get white reflections?

Answer (score 1):

You can just turn off Glossy in Cycles settings for this objects, and they will not be visible in reflections.[image]

You can achieve the same effect with shader, using node setup from this image[image]

Hope it helps.Cheers

Comment: This seemed to have little effect on the reflections, unchecking the glossy setting made no difference to the light behavior :(

Comment: Did you unchecked it for all objects?

Comment: Yes, I still could only minimise the reflection but the closest LEDs would still reflect the yellow.

Comment: You could mix with transparent shader using IsReflectionRay, but then it won't light on the ground plane, so I guess it won't solve the problem.